# Processing images without downloading using Scrapy Spiders

Tags: python, image, request, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm trying to use a Scrapy Spider to solve a problem (a programming question from HackThisSite):

(1) I have to log in a website, giving a username and a password (already done)

(2) After that, I have to access an image with a given URL (the image is only accessible to logged in users)

(3) Then, without saving the image in the hard disk, I have to read its information in a kind of buffer

(4) And the result of the function will fill a form and send the data to the website server (I already know how to do this step)

So, I can resume to question to: would it be possible (using a spider) to read an image accessible only by logged-in users and process it in the spider code?

I tried to research different methods, using item pipelines is not a good approach (I don't want to download the file).

The code that I already have is:

```
class ProgrammingQuestion2(Spider):

    name = 'p2'
    start_urls = ['https://www.hackthissite.org/']

    def parse(self, response):

        formdata_hts = {'username': <MY_USER_NAME>,
                'password': <MY_PASSWORD>,
                'btn_submit': 'Login'}

        return FormRequest.from_response(response,
                formdata=formdata_hts, callback=self.redirect_to_page)

    def redirect_to_page(self, response):

        yield Request(url='https://www.hackthissite.org/missions/prog/2/',
                callback=self.solve_question_2)

    def solve_question_2(self, response):

        open_in_browser(response)
        img_url = 'https://www.hackthissite.org/missions/prog/2/PNG'
        # What can I do here?
```

I expect to solve this problem using Scrapy functions, otherwise it would be necessary to log in the website (sending the form data) again.

Comment: "Then, without downloading the image, I have to read its pixels and run a function over the information" - how do you expect to read "it's pixels" when you don't have them? Maybe you mean _without saving it to hard drive?_

Comment: That's what I mean, I need to read the information of the img src without downloading it to the hard disk and, of course, I need to "download it" [post edited] (thx for the correction)

Comment: What's the deal with saving the file? Is it about the space occupied or is it something different?

Comment: When you download something in python it is stored in memory (RAM) and if you close the python process it is gone forever, you can chose to move it to your hard drive for persistent storage. Nevertheless the term download means moving some data from server to client, where you put the data on your client (be it hard drive or ram) is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a scrapy request to crawl the image and then callback to some other endpoint:

```
def parse_page(self, response):
    img_url = 'https://www.hackthissite.org/missions/prog/2/PNG'
    yield Request(img_url, callback=self.parse_image)

def parse_image(self, response):
    image_bytes = response.body
    form_data = form_from_image(image_bytes)
    # make form request
```

Comment: I don't understand, maybe I didnt explain well.. the link https://www.hackthissite.org/missions/prog/2/PNG is the img src, it's randomly generated when I'm on the page https://www.hackthissite.org/missions/prog/2 (which is accessible after logging in). So I would like to read the image src while I am logged on the img tag page

Comment: yes `parse_page` is your `...prog/2` url - you find the image url there and yield a request to it. `parse_image` is the image reponse with image information - you process the image data there.

Comment: That's just what I was looking for! It worked :) Thank you very much

Comment: @G.Dantas Feel free to accept the answer if it's sufficient enough :)